# Unable to Insert Records into Sqlite Database with Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am following a tutorial on from Practical Flask Web Development Tutorials in order to work on ideas for my computer programming course final project. I am currently stuck on a silent error that is preventing the insertion of records into the Sqlite database. I have been on this for about two days.
The code appears to be working up to the level of registration form input verification. There is no error log in the flask run console.
I will like to insert the records from the registration form into the database users table and also know why the console is not showing the cause of the error.
I will appreciate if someone can help with this mysterious error.

These is the short section of my code that I need help with.

```
@app.route("/register/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    error = ""
    try:
        # error = ""
        cursor, conn = connection()

        if request.method == "POST":

            # Check that all fields are filled
            if not request.form.get("firstname"):
                error = "Please provide firstname!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            if not request.form.get("surname"):
                error = "Please provide surname!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            if not request.form.get("username"):
                error = "Please provide username!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            if not request.form.get("password"):
                error = "Please provide provide!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            if not request.form.get("confirmation"):
                error = "Please provide password confirmation!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            # Validate matching passwords
            if request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirmation"):
                error = "Please provide matching passwords!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)


            if not request.form.get("email"):
                error = "Please provide email!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            if not request.form.get("age"):
                error = "Please provide age!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            if not request.form.get("birthday"):
                error = "Please provide birthday!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            print("All fields entered.")

            prior_username = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", username = request.form.get("username"))
            if len(prior_username) > 0:
                error = "Invalid username; choose a different one!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)
            else:
                firstname = request.form.get("firstname")
                surname = request.form.get("surname")
                username = request.form.get("username")
                password = request.form.get("password")
                confirmation = request.form.get("confirmation")
                email = request.form.get("email")
                age = request.form.get("age")
                birthday = request.form.get("birthday")
                tracking = "/introduction-to-python-programming/"
                rank = 0

                hash_pass = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))
                new_user = cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO users
                    (firstname, surname, username, hash, email, age, birthday, tracking, rank)
                    VALUES (:firstname, :surname, :username, :hash_pass, :email, :age, :birthday, :tracking, :rank)
                """, firstname, surname, username, hash_pass, email, age, birthday, tracking, rank)
                print("Insertion success")
                conn.commit()
                print("Commit success")
                conn.close()
                gc.collect()

                session["logged_in"] = True
                session["username"] = new_user
                return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))
        return render_template("register.html", error = error)
    except Exception as e:
        return render_template("register.html", error = error)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.jinja_env.auto_reload = True
    app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True
    app.run(debug = True)
```

This is the registration HTML file code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Register
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <div class="container">
        <h4>Please Register</h4>
        {% if error %}
            <p><strong>{{ error }}</strong></p>
        {% endif %}
        <form action="{{ url_for("register") }}" method="POST" class="form-group">
            <div class="msg2"></div>
            <div>
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter first name">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Enter surname">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label for="password">Confirmation</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirmation" id="confirmation" placeholder="Confirm password">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label for="age">Age</label>
                <input type="number" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Enter current age">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label for="birthday">Birthday</label>
                <input type="date" name="birthday" id="birthday">
            </div>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </form>
        {% if error %}
            <p><strong>{{ error }}</strong></p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you in advance.

===========================================

EDIT

Following the advice by @DinoCoderSaurus, I modified my code to pass (e) as the error message. The HTML page was then able to output the following error message:
"execute() takes no keyword argument"
Online search made me realise that sqlite3 module supports two kinds of placeholders: question marks (qmark style) and named placeholders (named style) https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute.

By modifying my select and insert queries into the qmark style, I was able to insert the records into the database.

This is the revised code:

```
@app.route("/register/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    error = ""
    try:
        # error = ""
        cursor, conn = connection()

        if request.method == "POST":

            # Check that all fields are filled
            if not request.form.get("firstname"):
                error = "Please provide firstname!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            if not request.form.get("surname"):
                error = "Please provide surname!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            if not request.form.get("username"):
                error = "Please provide username!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            if not request.form.get("password"):
                error = "Please provide provide!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            if not request.form.get("confirmation"):
                error = "Please provide password confirmation!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            # Validate matching passwords
            if request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirmation"):
                error = "Please provide matching passwords!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)


            if not request.form.get("email"):
                error = "Please provide email!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            if not request.form.get("age"):
                error = "Please provide age!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            if not request.form.get("birthday"):
                error = "Please provide birthday!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)

            print("All fields entered.")

            username = request.form.get("username")
            # prior_username = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", username)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", username)
            # print(cursor.fetchone())
            prior_username = cursor.fetchall()
            # conn.commit()
            if len(prior_username) > 0:
                error = "Invalid username; choose a different one!"
                return render_template("register.html", error = error)
            else:
                firstname = request.form.get("firstname")
                surname = request.form.get("surname")
                username = request.form.get("username")
                password = request.form.get("password")
                confirmation = request.form.get("confirmation")
                email = request.form.get("email")
                age = request.form.get("age")
                birthday = request.form.get("birthday")
                tracking = "/introduction-to-python-programming/"
                rank = 0

                hash_pass = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))
                new_user = cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO users
                    (firstname, surname, username, hash, email, age, birthday, tracking, rank)
                    VALUES (:firstname, :surname, :username, :hash_pass, :email, :age, :birthday, :tracking, :rank)
                """, (firstname, surname, username, hash_pass, email, age, birthday, tracking, rank,))
                print("Insertion success")
                conn.commit()
                print("Commit success")
                conn.close()
                gc.collect()

                session["logged_in"] = True
                session["username"] = new_user
                return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))
        return render_template("register.html", error = error)
    except Exception as e:
        return render_template("register.html", error = e)
```

Will now have to solve the new error message:
"The session is not available because no secret key was set. Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret."

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it failing silently because register is in "silent" mode? Since register is a huge `try` block, *any* Exception will `return render_template("register.html", error = error)` and `error` will be blank. You don't have a fighting chance. At least send `e` to register.html and get more feedback from the computer. That should get you on the way to troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you very much @DinoCoderSaurus. Never knew that. Currently at work; will implement that once I get home in the evening and give a feedback. I am super grateful.